# Loading another UIView directly from the main ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am in the process of creating an application. In the main ViewController I have created the menu. But I want to have a login screen (UIView) to appear before the menu is visible.

But because the menu loads as soon as I run the application I have decided to create another UIView controller and have that loaded on top of the main ViewController.

Therefore at the end of my main ViewController viewDidLoad I have added the following code to open on top of that view the login view

```
LoginPageView *loginPageView = [[LoginPageView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginPageView" bundle:nil];
loginPageView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:loginPageView animated:YES];
```

As I know the purpose of that code is to present another view, but unfortunately the login view does not appear. Only the main ViewController load.
Can anyone help me on that? Have you realised what exactly I want?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `viewDidLoad` method, the view exists, but there is no guarantee that the view is already part of the view hierarchy of your application. In fact, almost ain't.

What you can try is take that code in the `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Great your way works mate, but only in the ViewDidAppear, and therefore for a split second the menu is shown. Is there a better way to do it?
Or I have to use the main ViewController for the login screen and use a second ViewController for the menu?

Comment: A quick fix: set all the subviews hidden until `viewDidAppear:` happened. Or maybe if you don't animate the modal transition, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a UINavigationController.  Use this as your window's root view controller.  Set the UINavigationController to not show the navigation bar.

Set the navigation controller's child view controller to your login view controller.

When the user logs in successfully, create your main view controller and push it, like this:

```
MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithWhatever...];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainVC animated:YES];
```

When the user logs out, you can just do this to get back to the login VC:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```